# Cannot edit date field

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a problem with the date fields. When someone fill the date fields of my solution it's impossible of edit or delete the date. I'm notice that problem after i install IE11 on my machine, but i don't know for sure if the is his fault.

EDIT: It's a ASP.NET website. And it's a textbox. Backspace and delete keys not clean a Textbox with MaskedEditExtender

Here is the code from aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DataEntrada"
             runat="server"
             CssClass="textoDezPosicoes"
             OnTextChanged="DataEntrada_TextChanged"
             AutoPostBack="true"
             Enabled="true"
             Text='<%# Bind("DataEntrada","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDataEntrada"
                            runat="server"
                            ValidationGroup="Detalhar"
                            ControlToValidate="DataEntrada"
                            ErrorMessage="Informe um valor para o campo 'Data Entrada'."
                            Enabled="false"
                            Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtenderDataEntrada"
                        runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="DataEntrada"
                        Mask="99/99/9999"
                        MaskType="Date" />
<cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidatorDataEntrada"
                         runat="server"
                         ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtenderDataEntrada"
                         ControlToValidate="DataEntrada"
                         InvalidValueMessage="Data Entrada inválida"
                         InvalidValueBlurredMessage="*"
                         ValidationGroup="Detalhar"
                         MinimumValueBlurredText="*"
                         MinimumValue="01/01/1753"
                         MinimumValueMessage="A data deve ser maior que 01/01/1753"
                         ErrorMessage="MaskedEditValidatorDataEntrada" />
```

Comment: What date field? How someone fills the fields? You gave no details whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry for bad english, i'm from south america. When i say fill. i Want to mean that i have a field in my web application and when someone enters a date like "11/02/2012" is impossible of edit the field. And this is happen with all date fields.

Comment: No, it's not your English. You didn't give nearly enough details. Is this WinForms? ASP.NET website? What kind of "field"? What have you tried so far? ...

Comment: Please add those details to your post by editing. Add your markup as well (e.g. `<asp:TextBox ...>`) and how you set it as date field exactly. Also explain what you mean "cannot edit", you mean the field is readonly?

Comment: When i say "cannot edit" means that the user can enter the data but when he press backspace the date cannot be changed.

I add the code from the aspx above

Comment: Well, that's a bug in the custom controls you're using, either *MaskedEditExtender* or *MaskedEditValidator*, not in your own code. Ask the author of the controls to fix them, or explain where exactly you got them from and I'll try to take a look myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is Ajax Toolkit Version Issues. Try to use latest version of Ajax Toolkit to your project.

**( Or )**

- Create a script file with following function

  ```
  (function () 
  {
      try {
          var p = Sys.Extended.UI.MaskedEditBehavior.prototype,
              en = p._ExecuteNav;

          p._ExecuteNav = function (e) {
              var type = e.type;
              if (type == 'keydown') { e.type = 'keypress' };
              en.apply(this, arguments);
              e.type = type;
          }

      } 
      catch (e) {
          return;
      }
  })();
  ```
- Call the script file in your aspx page and check now

Plese refer more here

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26978
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/17166

Hope this help you